# Macbook asking for username password when connecting to WPA Personal network

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wpa2-psk

I have a network with WPA2 **Personal** encryption, so not Enterprise, but I have a Macbook here that's asking for a username & password, instead of only the password.

Other laptops do not have this issue, they can connect just fine.

How do I fix this?

I found someone with the same problem, but there's no solution posted on that website:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1776431-mac-thinks-the-wireless-network-is-wpa2-enterprise-but-it-isn-t

Comment: Are you sure it’s a Wi-Fi dialog and not a dialog asking to unlock your Keychain or something? Did you try deleting the network from the list of Preferred Networks in System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > Wi-Fi ?

Comment: Also, when asking macOS questions, please include the exact version of macOS you’re dealing with.

Comment: The version is 10.7.5. Yes I'm very sure its the WiFi dialog, see picture here: https://imgur.com/a/jYQEx. (translation, for the wireless network "name Office" is WPA2-access data on company level required). I've also tried removing the network, but it has no effect.

Comment: Wow, 10.7 is from 6+ years ago and I don’t recall hearing about any bug like this at the time. Maybe something about some modern Wi-Fi networks confuse that old codebase.